# Problem finding $Df(x_{1},x_{2},\dotsc, x_{n})(h_{1},h_{2}, \dotsc, h_{n}) $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let  $E_{i}$  be  banach  spaces  for  $i=1,2,\dotsc, n$ .

Let $f$  be  a  continuous  multilinear  function  from  $E_{1}\times E_{2}\times \dotsb \times E_{n}$  to  another  banach  space  $F$: $$f\ \ \ :\ \ \ E_{1}\times E_{2}\times \dotsb \times E_{n}  \rightarrow  F$$ Denote  a  point  in  the  domain  set  as  $$x=(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dotsc, x_{n}).$$
Then $$f(x+h)-f(x)\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n} {f(h_{1},h_{2},\dotsc, x_{i}, h_{i+1}, \dotsc, h_{n})} \ +\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{1},x_{2},\dotsc, h_{i},\dotsc, x_{n})}\ +\ f(h_{1},h_{2},....h_{n})$$

Now  I  know   $f(h_{1},h_{2},....h_{n})$ is $\mathcal o (\|(h_{1},h_{2},\dotsc, h_{n})\|)$  but  not  know  what  about  the  first  two  summands .

The  result  is  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{1},x_{2}, \dotsc, h_{i}, \dotsc, x_{n})}.$

It's  not clear to  me  why the other summand  would   be  $\mathcal o (\|(h_{1},h_{2},\dotsc,h_{n})\|)$.

Comment: such kind of problem is best solved using induction. Do you known the solution for the bilinear case?

Comment: Yes  I  have  done  the  bilinear  case  @user251257

Comment: Then just do an induction. Consider $f: (E_1\times \dotsb \times E_n) \times E_{n+1} \to F$ and apply the bilinear case and then the induction hypothesis on the first term.